# Problem with Vieta's formula and symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have this polynomial $X^{6}-4X^{5}+3X^{3}-4X^{2}+X+1$ and I want to calculate the sum  $\sum_{i=1}^{6}\left(r_{i}\right)^{5}$ with $r_i,i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ being its roots, but I find very hard to express $\sum_{i=1}^{6}\left(r_{i}\right)^{5}$ in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials and then use the Vieta's formula, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See *Newton-Girard identities* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#See_also) to have recursive relation  for power sums.

Comment: More precisely, here is the useful formula you can find in this Wikipedia article : $p_{5}=e_{1}^{5}-5e_{2}e_{1}^{3}
     +5e_{3}e_{1}^{2}+5e_{2}^{2}e_{1}-5e_{4}e_{1}
     -5e_{3}e_{2}+5e_{5}$

Comment: Why is the sum only to 5? Which root do you want to drop?

Comment: @Andrei it was a mistake, I'll edit it, sorry